# creating apollo-express-server with typescript and type-graphql error

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, apollo, typegraphql

I'm trying to set up an apollo server and an error shows up.

```
import { createConnection } from "typeorm";
import { Post } from "./entity/Post";
const express = require("express");
import { buildSchema } from "type-graphql";
import { ApolloServer } from "apollo-server-express";
import { PostResolver } from "./Resolvers/post";

createConnection()
  .then(async (connection) => {
    console.log("Inserting a new user into the database...");
    const post = new Post();
    post.firstName = "Timber";
    post.lastName = "Saw";
    post.age = 25;
    await connection.manager.save(post);
    console.log("Saved a new user with id: " + post.id);

    console.log("Loading users from the database...");
    const posts = await connection.manager.find(Post);
    console.log("Loaded users: ", posts);

    const app = express();
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on PORT: ${PORT}`));

    const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
      schema: await buildSchema({
        resolvers: [PostResolver],
      }),
    });
    await apolloServer.start();
    apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

***[ERROR] 16:49:21 ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/index.ts:27:43 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ schema: GraphQLSchema; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Config'.
Type '{ schema: GraphQLSchema; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Config': formatError, debug, rootValue, validationRules, and 6 more.***

I've tried installing dependencies again, changed TypeScript config, restarting the whole project but nothing seems to fix the problem. Any clue?

Comment: I've gone through the documentation and it's literally like that but still causes me a problem. Don't know why.

Comment: Try ```const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({ schema: buildSchemaSync({ resolvers: PostResolver], }), });```

Comment: Nope, same error. Thanks for the reply though!

Comment: Move ```app.listen(...)``` as last operation (currently after .applyMiddleware). Remove ```await apolloServer.start();```. The last three lines should be ```const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(...); apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app }); app.listen(...);```

Comment: Didn't work, but I've just started all the project again from scratch and now it does. I was initializing it with ```typeorm init --name MyProject --database postgres``` from typeorm documentation, this command generates a boilerplate for you. I guess that was the problem, honestly I don't know. Thanks for the replies!

Comment: Please can you share what you now have @BrunoAburto. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @Mel yeah, I solved the problem by starting the whole project from scratch. As I said in the other comment, I was initializing the project by the TypeORM generator thing. What I did was to create the whole structure by myself, and it worked.